# Sphere on a rotating object isn't falling if I don't add force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

In the scene, ladder looking object rotating by Y. If I don't add force to my sphere, gravity isn't pulling it.

Sphere moving

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    Vector3 MoveVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    rb.AddForce((MoveVector * PlayerSpeed));
```

Ladder looking object

```
gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
new Vector3(
    gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, 
    gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + (Time.deltaTime * speed),
    gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z)
);
```

Update1: also sphere don't recognise colliders if I dont add force to sphere.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should move a "Player" with rigidbody.velocity, not with AddForce (that should be used if you want to push one object... not if you read player input).

For the colliders problem check if the ladder got a collider, both the player and the ladder should have a collider.

Also check Constraints in the rigidbody component (y should not be checked) the global gravity and time settings:
Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics and Edit -> Project Settings -> Time

Comment: My all colliders was fine while I was adding force. But when I stop moving object by input, object was unresponsive. Using velocity instead of addforce in input moving fixed everything (including responsivity, gravity while not moving). But I wonder was the problem "0" value of addForce in every update?

Comment: Yes, I think it make sense. addForce is a method that is needed for "push an object", so if you add a force of zero it make sense that the object become unresponsive. It's a great thing for jump (for example) where you need to apply a force by pushing a button a single time (against gravity).